# Меню на jquery - при открытии не работают ссылки

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

http://thetranslte.com/ подскажите почему в меню города при выборе не перекидывает по ссылке? Ничего не происходит. Делал на JQuery.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
 $("#dropdown").on("click", function(e){
 e.preventDefault(); 
 if($(this).hasClass("open")) { 
   $(this).removeClass("open"); 
   $(this).children("ul").slideUp("fast"); 
 } else { 
   $(this).addClass("open"); 
   $(this).children("ul").slideDown("fast"); 
 } 
}); 
</script>
```

Comment: что вы делали на JQuery? нам бы код увидеть

Comment: <script type="text/javascript"> 
$("#dropdown").on("click", function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  
  if($(this).hasClass("open")) {
    $(this).removeClass("open");
    $(this).children("ul").slideUp("fast");
  } else {
    $(this).addClass("open");
    $(this).children("ul").slideDown("fast");
  }
});

</script>

Comment: Вот весь код jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть большая вероятность что ссылки не работают из за e.preventDefault();  Попробуйте без него.

Answer (score 2):

Не видя HTML сложно судить, но похоже что проблема в `e.preventDefault()` -  этот метод предотвращает выполнение действия (клика в данном случае) для всего элемента #dropdown, включая дочерние элементы (в т.ч. ссылки в выпадающем меню).